# How to create dynamic squares using flexbox?

Tags: javascript, css, dynamic, flexbox, resize

I am having a few difficulties setting up the dynamic portion of the sketch project i am doing. The idea that i want to implement next is that the amount of squares (divs) changes inside the predetermined container and the boxes change size to always fill out the container. What happens is if the number of boxes is over 256 they overspill on the bottom and if it's not enough they just don't fill the extra space of the container.

link to codepen - https://codepen.io/kcolrehs/pen/eYKZXoa

**css**

```
  *,
  *:before,
  *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
  }

  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
  }

  .grid {
    border: 0.1px solid black;
    width: 15.63px;
    height: 15.63px;
  }
```

**js**

```
for (let i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    const grid = document.createElement('div');
    grid.classList.add('grid');
    container.appendChild(grid);
}
```

question is : how do i style the boxes that they would automaticly change sizes based on the ammount of them inside the perent container?
for ex:

- User imputs 64x64 and the grid changes to match the user imput.  user
- Imputs 4x4 the grid changes to match the user imput.
- The container itself has the same size.

I've tried using all sorts of flex grow and shrink properties, but it didin't really do anything apart from deforming the squeres.

I've tried not using predetermant height and width of the squere divs , using margint top and maching width but it didin't work as well.

By now i am thinking of just switching to grid layout and re-working my java to generate column and horizontal squeres and making a grid like that , but before i am doing that i was thinking maybe theres a solution im not thinkign of here.

Comment: Assuming the container is always a fixed size, then the solution is just `box size = container width / number of boxes`. If I've misunderstood what you're asking, please edit the question to include a clear description of *what the correct behaviour should be.*

Comment: With CSS Grid you generally just add the items you need in a grid to the grid, and let the grid organise the columns and rows according to the CSS you set up.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @Rory McCrossan for puting me on the right direction:

```
slider.addEventListener('change', function () {
    let boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.grid');
    boxes.forEach(box => {
        box.remove();//removes old grid
    });
    createGrid() //makes new grid afte reset
})


function createGrid() {
    for (let i = 0; i < (slider.value * slider.value); i++) {
        const grid = document.createElement('div');
        let a = slider.value;
        const boxSize = 250 / a; // creates the dynamic squeres
        grid.classList.add('grid');
        grid.style.width = boxSize + 'px';
        grid.style.height = boxSize + 'px';
        container.appendChild(grid);
    }
}
```

I'll post this in case sameone someday will have similar issues